# python: оптимизация загрузки библиотек/пакетов/модулей

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, импорт

ситуация следующая:

бэкенд на python, каждый раз выполнение скрипта занимает заметное время (секунда и больше, хотя полезный функционал отрабатывает за миллисекунды)

оказалось, что дело в загрузке библиотек (pandas и т.д.)

поскольку функционал этих библиотек не всегда нужен (в зависимости от полученных от клиента данных), то перенос `import` внутрь функций, в которых нужен данный функционал из начала скрипта частично решил проблему

подскажите -  можно ли как-то более элегантно решить проблему, например чтоб загрузка библиотеки выполнялась при первом вызове функции из библиотеки или еще каким-то способом повысить производительность

Comment: а нельзя ему все время жить, реагируя на запросы

Comment: т.е. поднять на скрипке соединение и ждать пока запросы будут приходить?

как-то привычно было думать, что такими вещами занимается ОС и т.д., т.е. скрипт может и весит в памяти постоянно

т.е. я к тому, чтоб не вводить дополнительный функционал направленный на прослушивание запросов от клиентов

Comment: У вас веб приложение или что?

Comment: да, клиент шлет запросы на сервер, на сервере вызывается условный `client_server.py`, прописанный в IIS, который дергает в зависимости от того, что получил по POST ту или иную py с нужным функционалом, после чего выдает print(), получаемый клиентом (по сути такой же подход как с php)

Comment: А сам сервер на питоне? Если да то сделайте все импорты в главном скрипте и передавайте их как аргументы. Или я не понял чего то.

Comment: не понял на счет передачи как аргумент - сервер - это скрипт к которому обращается клиент (условно js на клиенте `const response = await fetch('localhost/client_server.py', {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: data})`, на сервере стоит IIS, вызывается `client_server.py`, делает свои дела и выдает результат через `print`

Comment: ну, вот пусть он не вызывает скрипт, а отдает ему запрос. Тогда и ответ будет быстрый